# Export data from datagrid to MS Excel

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, export-to-excel

I developed a web application in ASP.Net and VB.In tried to display report in datagrid.And there is an option to export report from datagrid to MS Excel.But due to excess amount of data i am not able to export to into MS excel.With less amount of data export function works properly.Is there any option to export data page by page,or any other option? Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: On which way have you exported the data to excel?

Answer (score 0):

you could export it as a CSV. the overhead should be a lot less.